# Woo 3.0.8 Ajax fragments NOT updating Cart Menu

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

We are using [WP Cart Menu Pro](https://wpovernight.com/downloads/menu-cart-pro/) and on our shop page we have Ajax add to cart, which is working fine but its not updating the Items in the Cart Menu.

This has only started to happen with auto update to WooCommerce 3.0.8. I have done some research and added the below code to our functions.php page:

```
function my_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();    
    ?><a class="wpmenucart-contents" href="https://www.springbokbbq.co.uk/cart/" title="View your shopping cart">
        <i class="wpmenucart-icon-shopping-cart-5"></i>
        <span class="cartcontents"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?></span>
        </a><?php 
    $fragments['a.wpmenucart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
```

Did anybody else come across this issue with the Woo update?

---

EDIT:

I have checked the chrome console: when I click Add to Cart I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a(...).addClass(...).fadeTo(...).block is not a function
    at String.<anonymous> (add-to-cart.min.js?ver=3.0.8:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.b.updateFragments (add-to-cart.min.js?ver=3.0.8:4)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

I Don't get this error when removing items from the cart and it updates the menu Cart Items on cart page.

Comment: what woocommerce version you used before autoupdate?

Comment: can you provide the link of your site so I can understand the issue.

Comment: Could you share the WP Cart Menu Pro plugin information like plugin author or plugin url?

Comment: This is a javascript issue related to the WP Cart Menu plugin, so you should **better open a ticket support** as they are pretty **reactive** and **outstanding**… May be you should try to roll-back to 3.0.7 to see if something change (You can stop auto updates in wp-config.php file)

Comment: Hi John! Can you provide the URL of your website?

Comment: from the error message you provided I can guess that the blockUI library is not loaded. please provide the link for the site to investigate the issue thoroughly. have you tried to reload the cache? (hard reload or basic reload with ctrl+f5) ?